# Deploying a split-merge service for Azure SQL Elastic (sharded) databases

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale, azure-elastic-sharding

I am trying to follow [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-configure-deploy-split-and-merge) for deploying a split-merge service (Azure Elastic Database... tools).

The first complication is that the doc instructs me to create an "Azure Cloud Service."  The closest thing to that seems to be "Cloud service (classic)," so that's what I created.

When it came to creating a self-signed cert, I had to translate the parameters for makecert (which [is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx) and no longer seems to be present in any SDKs) to the powershell `New-SelfSignedCertificate` cmdlet.  The relevant params I passed to the cmdlet were:

- Subject: CN=*.cloudapp.net
- KeySpec: KeyExchange
- TextExtension: 2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2

I finally got the certificate created/exported/uploaded, got the service configuration file completed and created the service.  Azure portal reports the web and workers running, but I can't hit the service URL (*403 access denied* even after prompting me to select my certificate).  I confirmed that my certificate thumbprint shows correctly in the various places in the service configuration (DataEncryptionPrimaryCertificateThumbprint, DataEncryptionPrimary, AdditionalTrustedRootCertificationAuthorities, AllowedClientCertificateThumbprints, DataEncryptionPrimaryCertificateThumbprint).  My certificate's thumbprint also shows as the thumbprint in configuration under the "Certificates" section as SSL, CA, and DataEncryptionPrimary.

The only thing I can think of that is causing the access denied is something mentioned in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates), "*If you are using self-signed certificates, you will need to disable certificate chain validation.*"  The PowerShell cmdlet that it shows to use to disable chain validation in that case (for an API service; no clue how that differs from my service) fails with *InvalidOperation.*

Is there some way for me to disable certificate chain validation for my "classic" cloud service?  Other suggestions of things to check?